# Cannot find module 'D:\Resources\DevOps\eslint\bin\eslint.js'

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to integrate eslint with react
I'm getting this error when I run lint command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzW6y.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

because you installed eslint locally (inside your current project), you have to call it from .node_modules folder of your project like this

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx`